# How the best way to create unique code invoice

Tags: c#

I learned to create code invoices using the value from the combobox to fill in the textbox.

this is my code

```
    string GenerateCode()
    {
        int plus = 1;
        string no = "0000";
        string front = no + plus;
        string mid = sCode;
        string last = DateTime.Now.ToString("/MM/yyyy");
        string fullcode = front.Substring(front.Length-4,4)+ "/" + mid + last;

        if(tDAL.CheckCode (fullcode))
        {
            plus = plus + 1;
            front = no + plus;
            fullcode = front.Substring(front.Length - 4, 4)+"/"+ mid + last;

        }
        return fullcode;
    }
```

this my code for to display the created code

```
tb_invoice.text = fullcode;
```

this is my form_load

```
private void PurchaseandSalesFm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadCode();
            tb_invoice.Text = GenerateCode();
        }
```

this is the result so far

> Output : 0001/XXL-35/02/2019

Is there any suggestion for me? or the better code?
because I still have doubt with my code
And also still looking for ways to change month numbers to Roman's letter

Sorry if I asking to much but I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trt set `DataSource` after `ValueMember`.

```
    cb_codetrans.DisplayMember = "title";
    cb_codetrans.ValueMember = "title"; 
    cb_codetrans.DataSource = codetransDT;
```

This because set `DataSource` will trigger `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: it work's (**0001/SSL-30/X/2018**) but the textbox value not change when i try to change the combobox value. but thank you for your help sir.